# Subprocess fails on Popen when using with gevent 1.2.2

Tags: python, flask, subprocess, gevent

I have a flask app that uses websockets. For websockets I installed `gevent 1.2.2`. In the app I'm trying to call a subprocess:

```
def runsub(exec,filePath,input):
    prc = Popen([exec,filePath],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
    return prc.communicate(input)
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/apps/utils.py", line 1956, in runsub
    prc = Popen([exec,filePath],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1254, in _execute_child
    self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fork_exec'
```

It runs fine when I call the same function directly, i.e. without flask or gevent:

```
>>> include utils
>>> utils.runsub('someapp','somefile','someinput')
```

Here's the odd part: if i uninstall gevent and install eventlet instead (for websockets), everything works fine (without any changes to the code). 
Unfortunately I can't use eventlet since the client has a requirement of using gevent (for whatever reason).

Has anyone come across this error? Or any idea how to go around it?

Am running python 3.6 on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

UPDATE: same thing happens on Mac OS X 10.12.6

**UPDATE 2:** Here's a possible workaround provided by @Hannu : github.com/celery/celery/issues/3230

**UPDATE 3:** I found that if I run the app using the new flask way, everything seems to work:

```
FLASK_APP=myapp.py flask run --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0
```

Just a note, the "old" way to run is to simply call `python myapp.py`

Comment: Take a look at this. Not familiar with your environment as such, but it seems to be a bug and there might be a workaround or patch.  https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3230

Comment: A smell: you're redefining `exec`, a built-in. This might clash with something. The standard way in Python to use identifiers that clash with keywords is to append an underscore: `exec_`.

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen when the "monkey patching" is done half.

Make sure you do monkey patching at the very beginning when the program start.

```py
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
```

It's best to put it before any package import.

In your case, it's likely on the first line of `app.py`

That make sure gevent replaces all synchronous packages with asynchronous packages whenever available.